# Google.LineChart with Asp.Net MVC 3.0

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How can we use the google Line Chart with asp.net MVC 3.0 Any .dll to add or reference Help me to add google Line Chart in MVC 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [javascript to configure it](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/linechart.html#Example). You may also checkout the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/index.html) start page.